How do i read the number of baked Frames of a Bake Node in geometry nodes with Python?
I'm trying to read the number of baked frames of the baked node. It is displayed above the node in the Picture below, but I can't find a way to get it with Python.


Does this answer help?

No. It doesn't have attributes that show if it is baked and if it is which frames.
